# Removing JTable from content panel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jframe

I'm using a JTable to graphically display search results for an application I'm developing.  I would like the ability to remove a table once it's not longer needed, and then replace it with a newly created table. Here is how I'm currently adding the table to my JFrame:

```
    userLibrary = new CustomLibrary(users, LIBRARY_WIDTH, LIBRARY_HEIGHT);
    userLibrary.setOpaque(true);
    userLibrary.setBounds(LIBRARY_START_X, LIBRARY_START_Y, LIBRARY_WIDTH, LIBRARY_HEIGHT);
    getContentPane().add(userLibrary);
```

My custom Library (Which extends JPanel) does the following:

```
public CustomLibrary(LinkedList<User> usernames, int width, int height) {
    CustomTable table = new CustomTable(userRows,columnNames);
    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

    // Add the scroll pane to this panel.
    add(scrollPane);
}
```

now this all works fine and displays my table, but I can't figure out how to completely remove the table from my content pane.  I've tried calling

```
getContentPane().remove(userLibrary);
```

But this appears to do nothing.

So my general question is.  How do I completely remove a table from my JFrame once I've already created it and drawn it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I would like the ability to remove a table once it's not longer needed, and then replace it with a newly created table.

The easiest way is to just replace the TableModel of the JTable:

```
table.setModel( yourNewlyCreatedTableModel );
```

No need to create a JTable or a JScrollPane.

Answer (score 1):

To remove and replace it with another component:

```
contentPanel.remove(table);
contentPanel.add(component, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

After adding/removing components you should do:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint(); // sometimes needed
```

Usually a JTable is displayed in a JScrollPane. So maybe a better solution is to use:

```
scrollPane.setViewportView( anotherComponent );
```

Comment: Even though it answers the question, it was a 'wrong question'.  The better (by far) approach was outlined by camickr.